# JMS Tutorial j2eeadmin and j2ee commands

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms

I'm trying to follow the "Java Messaging Service API Tutorial", I have installed the "java_ee_sdk_6u4", but the tutorial is about an old java ee SDK, 1.3.1.

The tutorial asks to start the J2EE server by entering the command:

```
j2ee -verbose
```

and later it asks to create a queue named MyQueue using this command:

```
j2eeadmin -addJmsDestination MyQueue queue
```

I can't find those two commands in the src files:

```
$ ls glassfish3/bin
$ ls glassfish3/glassfish/bin
```

don't list anyone of them, are these commands updated or do I need to install something else?

Comment: why not follow a modern tutorial?

Comment: Yes, I found 2 chapters about JMS, in the j2EE 6 tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Java EE SDK you downloaded is bundled with glassfish which is an open source application server.You can find documentation on using glassfish on http://glassfish.java.net/docs/index.html .
The documentation you are using might be old ,but glassfish has pretty good documentation and a nice admin console for creating JMS administred objects.